# How to sort the digits within subgroups of a number's digits which are separated by "0", and remove the zeros?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that contains an integer number with the condition that the **number 0 (zero)** in the variable is a **separator** between one number and another. The numbers will be separated and sorted based on the numbers in the numbers **themselves**. After that, the ordered numbers will be combined again without a separator with the output in the form of an integer number.

So example:

```
dividerSort(74108520159);
```

the output I want is
`147258159`

but my output is:
`112455789`

This is so far I try, hope you can help me figure out

```js
function dividerSort(num){
    const divider = 0     
        let getNum = Array.from(String(num), Number)     
        getNum = getNum.filter(item =>{         
                return item !== divider   
         })
        getNum = getNum.sort()
        getNum = getNum.join('');
        console.log(getNum);
}
dividerSort(74108520159);
```

Comment: You keep using “number” when you mean either “number” or “digit”.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```js
function dividerSort(num){
  var result = '';
  var items = num.toString().split('0'); // items = ["741", "852", "159"]
  items.forEach( item => {
    result = result + item.split('').sort().join('') // see Explanation
  });
  console.log('Result: ', result);
}
dividerSort(74108520159); // Result:  147258159
```

**Explanation:** [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) `item` in `items` split at every charachter `item.split('')`.
Example: `"741"` becomes an array `['7', '4', '1']`. This array can be sorted simply with [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) so it becomes `['1', '4', '7']` which will then be joined back together to a string with [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) . At every iteration concatenate the result to result...

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string with zero, map splitted substrings with splitted by chcaracter, sort them and join them. Then join the mapped part strings.

```js
function dividerSort(num){
    return +String(num)
        .split('0')
        .map(s => s.split('').sort().join(''))
        .join('');
}

console.log(dividerSort(74108520159)); // 147258159
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `String.split()` method to split.

### usage

```js
let number = 1230456098;
let stringified = number.toString(); // to use String.split ()

let splitted = stringified.split("0"); // ["123", "456", "98"]

// convert those "string" elements of `splitted` array into numbers, and then apply sorting algorithm.

splitted = splitted.map(split=>parseInt(split));  // [123, 456, 98]
```

### TLDR;

1. convert that integer to a string, using `Number.toString()`,
2. use String.split() to split the string,
3. map through the splitted array and convert those string elements into numbers, using
   `splitted.map(split=>parseInt(split));`

Answer (score -1):

```
function dividerSort(num){
  return `${num}`.split('0').map(x => x.split('').sort().join('')).join('0')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use split() method for accomplish this. We just need to pass 0 as separator and sort them. After sorting, we can join them using join() method.

```js
function divideAndSort(n){
  var result = '';
  var items = n.toString().split('0'); // items = ["741", "852", "159"]
  items.forEach( item => {
    result = result + item.split('').sort().join('')
  });
  console.log('Result: ', result);
}
divideAndSort(74108520159); 
// Result:  147258159
```